# Изменение элементов списка python

Tags: python

Как реализовать функцию на языке Python которая будет:

1. Принимать строку
2. Преобразовывать строку в список и заменять все элементы списка кроме N-первых на определенный элемент
3. Преобразовывать список обратно в строку и возвращать ее

Comment: Для корректного ответа на Ваш вопрос нужны: 1. Образец исходника (то есть самой строки которую Вы будете преобразовывать). 2. Пример желаемого результата. Иначе это будет "гадание на кофейной гуще"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без преобразования в список , если  функция принимает строку и возвращает строку то можно сделать ваше преобразование без использование промежуточного списка если есть такая возможность , и такая возможность есть

```
def modification(to_convert, position, value):
  return to_convert[:position:] + str(value) * (len(to_convert)-position) 

print(modification('ivanivanovichivanov', 9, 0))
```

результат работы програмы :

```
 ivanivano0000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(s, N, x):
  a = list(s)
  a[N:] = [x] * (len(a) - N) 
  return str(a)

print(foo("1f315v535", 3, 7))
```

Comment: Это плохо ответ. Не потому, что он не работает (код верный). Вы дали просто кусок кода без пояснений, что именно он делает и как.